The issue of positioning discrepancies between Android and iOS
I'm having issues with this part of my Next.js code. Why is the positioning of the span that contains the number not displaying properly on iOS, but working fine on Android? What I basically want is to display the number on the top right of the icons.

here is my code:
`
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='flex  gap-4 lg:gap-6'>
            <motion.div
              initial={{ width: '18rem' }}
              animate={{ width: isCollapsed ? '2.5rem' : '18rem' }}
              transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
              className='relative col-span-12   md:col-span-5 lg:col-span-4 xl:col-span-3'
            >
  <div
                style={{ zIndex: 2 }}
                className='col-span-12 md:col-span-5  lg:col-span-4 xl:col-span-3'
              >
                <div
                  className={flex flex-col  rounded-2xl bg-white p-3 shadow-lg sm:p-4 ${isCollapsed ? 'items-center' : 'lg:p-6'}}
                >
                  <button
                    onClick={toggleSidebar}
                    className={${isCollapsed ? ' h-8 w-3' : ' h-10 w-4'} absolute right-0 top-4 hidden rounded-bl-md rounded-tl-md bg-primary-400 text-white lg:block}
                  >
                    {!isCollapsed ? (
                      <ChevronLeftIcon className='h-5 w-5' />
                    ) : (
                      <ChevronRightIcon className='h-4 w-4' />
                    )}
                  </button>
 <div className='mb-10'>
                    {!isCollapsed && (
                      <span className='clr-neutral-400 mb-4 block text-xs'>
                        LISTING
                      </span>
                    )}
                    <ul className='flex flex-col gap-3'>
                      <li>
                        <Link
                          href='/user-booking'
                          className={link clr-neutral-500 flex items-center gap-2 hover:text-primary-500 ${
                            path === '/user-booking' && 'text-primary-500'
                          }}
                        >
                          {!isCollapsed ? (
                            <>
                              <CalendarDaysIcon className='h-5 w-5' />

                              <span className='block font-medium'>
                                My Bookings{' '}
                              </span>
                            </>
                          ) : (
                            <TooltipProvider>
                              <Tooltip>
                                <TooltipTrigger>
                                  {' '}
                                  <span>
                                    <CalendarDaysIcon className='h-6 w-6' />
                                  </span>
                                </TooltipTrigger>
                                <TooltipContent>
                                  <p>My Bookings</p>
                                </TooltipContent>
                              </Tooltip>
                            </TooltipProvider>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <Link
                          href='/user-listing'
                          className={link clr-neutral-500 flex items-center gap-2 hover:text-primary-500 ${
                            path === '/user-listing' && 'text-primary-500'
                          }}
                        >
                          {!isCollapsed ? (
                            <>
                              <ClipboardIcon className='h-5 w-5' />

                              <span className='block font-medium'>
                                My Listings{' '}
                              </span>
                            </>
                          ) : (
                            <TooltipProvider>
                              <Tooltip>
                                <TooltipTrigger>
                                  {' '}
                                  <span>
                                    <ClipboardIcon className='h-6 w-6' />
                                  </span>
                                </TooltipTrigger>
                                <TooltipContent>
                                  <p> My Listings</p>
                                </TooltipContent>
                              </Tooltip>
                            </TooltipProvider>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <Link
                          href='/user-wishlist'
                          className={link clr-neutral-500 flex items-center justify-between gap-2 hover:text-primary-500 ${
                            path === '/user-wishlist' && 'text-primary-500'
                          }}
                        >
                          {!isCollapsed ? (
                            <>
                              <span className='flex items-center gap-2'>
                                <HeartIcon className='h-5 w-5' />

                                <span className='block font-medium'>
                                  My Wishlists
                                </span>
                              </span>
                              <span className='grid h-6 w-6 place-content-center rounded-full bg-primary-500 text-sm text-white'>
                                4
                              </span>
                            </>
                          ) : (
                            <>
                              <TooltipProvider>
                                <Tooltip>
                                  <TooltipTrigger>
                                    {' '}
                                    <span className='relative'>
                                      <HeartIcon className='h-6 w-6' />
                                      <span className='absolute right-[-2px] top-[-2px] grid h-4 w-4 place-content-center rounded-full bg-primary-500 text-[12px] text-white'>
                                        1
                                      </span>
                                    </span>
                                  </TooltipTrigger>
                                  <TooltipContent>
                                    <p>My Wishlists</p>
                                  </TooltipContent>
                                </Tooltip>
                              </TooltipProvider>
                            </>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <Link
                          href='/user-shortlet'
                          className={link clr-neutral-500 flex items-center justify-between gap-2 hover:text-primary-500 ${
                            path === '/user-shortlet' && 'text-primary-500'
                          }}
                        >
                          {!isCollapsed ? (
                            <>
                              <span className='flex items-center gap-2'>
                                <ClipboardDocumentCheckIcon className='h-5 w-5' />

                                <span className='block font-medium'>
                                  My Shortlets
                                </span>
                              </span>
                              {userShortletProperties?.length > 0 && (
                                <span className='grid h-6 w-6 place-content-center rounded-full bg-primary-500 text-sm text-white'>
                                  {userShortletProperties.length}
                                </span>
                              )}
                            </>
                          ) : (
                            <>
                              <TooltipProvider>
                                <Tooltip>
                                  <TooltipTrigger>
                                    {' '}
                                    <span className='relative'>
                                      <ClipboardDocumentCheckIcon className='h-6 w-6' />
                                      {userShortletProperties?.length > 0 && (
                                        <span className='absolute right-[-2px] top-[-2px] grid h-4 w-4 place-content-center rounded-full bg-primary-500 text-[12px] text-white'>
                                          {userShortletProperties.length}
                                        </span>
                                      )}
                                    </span>
                                  </TooltipTrigger>
                                  <TooltipContent>
                                    <p> My Shortlets</p>
                                  </TooltipContent>
                                </Tooltip>
                              </TooltipProvider>
                            </>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <Link
                          href='/manage-shortlet'
                          className={link clr-neutral-500 flex items-center justify-between gap-2 hover:text-primary-500 ${
                            path === '/manage-shortlet' && 'text-primary-500'
                          }}
                        >
                          {!isCollapsed ? (
                            <>
                              <span className='flex items-center gap-2'>
                                <CalendarIcon className='h-5 w-5' />

                                <span className='block font-medium'>
                                  Manage shortlet
                                </span>
                              </span>
                              {approvalRequests?.length > 0 && (
                                <span className='grid h-6 w-6 place-content-center rounded-full bg-primary-500 text-sm text-white'>
                                  {approvalRequests?.length}
                                </span>
                              )}
                            </>
                          ) : (
                            <>
                              <TooltipProvider>
                                <Tooltip>
                                  <TooltipTrigger>
                                    {' '}
                                    <span className='relative'>
                                      <CalendarIcon className='h-6 w-6' />
                                      <span className='absolute right-[-2px] top-[-2px] grid h-4 w-4 place-content-center rounded-full bg-primary-500 text-[12px] text-white'>
                                        1
                                      </span>
                                    </span>
                                  </TooltipTrigger>
                                  <TooltipContent>
                                    <p> Manage shortlet</p>
                                  </TooltipContent>
                                </Tooltip>
                              </TooltipProvider>
                            </>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                      {/* <li>
                        <Link
                          href='/featured-listing'
                          className={link clr-neutral-500 flex items-center gap-2 hover:text-primary-500 ${
                            path === '/featured-listing' && 'text-primary-500'
                          }}
                        >
                          {!isCollapsed ? (
                            <>
                              <CheckBadgeIcon className='h-5 w-5' />

                              <span className='block font-medium'>
                                Featured Listings{' '}
                              </span>
                            </>
                          ) : (
                            <TooltipProvider>
                              <Tooltip>
                                <TooltipTrigger>
                                  {' '}
                                  <span>
                                    <CheckBadgeIcon className='h-6 w-6' />
                                  </span>
                                </TooltipTrigger>
                                <TooltipContent>
                                  <p> Featured Listings</p>
                                </TooltipContent>
                              </Tooltip>
                            </TooltipProvider>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                      </li> */}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
 </div>
              </div>
            </motion.div>

<div/>

The code actually works well on andriod:

